# Google Api in Excel to calculate Distance between coordinates

Tags: excel, google-maps-api-3, vba

I have four columns in my spreadsheet. Two have the starting points' longitude and latitude, and the other two columns contains the destinations' longitude and latitude. I am using this code to try and calculate the distance in miles between the two:

```
    'Calculate Google Maps distance between two addresses
Public Function GetDistance(start As String, dest As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
    firstVal = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
    secondVal = "+UK&destinations="
    lastVal = "+UK&mode=car&language=en&sensor=false"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """distance"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = """value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    tmpVal = Replace(matches(0).SubMatches(0), ".", Application.International(xlListSeparator))
    GetDistance = CDbl(tmpVal)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetDistance = -1
End Function
```

It seems to work when I manually type in the coordinates as =Getdistance("36.0202, -80.123", "36.1237, -80.1287"), but my problem is I can't figure out how to select the cells to do it many times. I am trying to make it so it would look like =getdistance(C2:D2,E2:F2) essentially. When I try and enter something like that I get a  "#Value!" error. Is there anyway to achieve my goal?

Comment: try `=getcoordinate(C2&", " & D2,E2&", " &F2)` the formula is looking for a string and you are trying to pass a range.

Comment: Came back with a "#Name?" error. Let me try it with the correct line. Should be a =getdistance(....) function

Comment: Sorry I copied and pasted yours it should be `=GetDistance(C2&", " & D2,E2&", " &F2)`

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it in the original post too. But that didn't work either. Came back with a (1.000) for every cell.

Comment: Could I change the formula to look for a number instead of a string?